# Adding values of similar arrays

Tags: python, arrays

The main objective is to get rid of similar numbers next to each other (for example, in the first line, if it is `T1000,8,8,Error` the initial program gets rid of it) but unfortunately, the problem that arose was that sometimes the csv file contains lines such as above. I want to tackle these values separately. Here, the first line and the second line `T1000,8,4` when added together become `T1000,8,8,Error` which is then removed. Similarly the last 3 values `S5214,20,8,Error`, `S5214,20,4,Error` and `S5214,20,8,Error` becomes `S5214,20,20,Error` and then gets removed. I've been working on it for a bit and I can't seem to get my head around it. Thanks soo much for the help!

```
with open('target.csv', 'r') as new:

    yes = []
    y = []
    for line in new:
        y.append(line)
        print(line)

    for n in range(0,len(y)-1):
        x1 = int(y[n].split(',')[1]) + int(y[n+1].split(',')[1])
        x2 = int(y[n].split(',')[2]) + int(y[n+1].split(',')[2])
        y1 = int(y[n].split(',')[2])
        y2 = int(y[n].split(',')[1])
        y3 = int(y[n+1].split(',')[2])
        y4 = int(y[n+1].split(',')[1])

        if y[n].split(',')[0] == y[n+1].split(',')[0]:
            if x1 == y1:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[1] = t[2]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])

            elif x1 == y2:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[2] = t[1]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])

            elif x2 == y1:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[1] = t[2]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])

            elif x2 == y2:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[2] = t[1]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])
                print(y)

            elif x1 == y3:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[1] = t[2]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])

            elif x1 == y4:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[2] = t[1]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])

            elif x2 == y3:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[1] = t[2]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])

            elif x2 == y4:
                print(x2)
                t = y[n].split(',')
                t[2] = t[1]
                y[n] = ",".join(t)
                print(y[n])
```

My csv file is as follows:

```
T1000,8,4,Error
T1000,8,4,Error
S1234,2,4,Error
C1234,3,2,Error
S1348,4,2,Error
S5214,20,8,Error
S5214,20,4,Error
S5214,20,8,Error
```

Comment: without having read the question, first impressions first. If ever your code basically looks like copy paste of the same 4 lines with small differences 8 times or something, you need to revisit what youre doing and see if you cannot use a loop instead perhaps.

Comment: It's not really clear what your expected output is. In this description: `T1000,8,4 when added together become T1000,8,8,Error which is then removed,` what exactly is being removed? The original, the summed version, both. It would help if you added the final expected result.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear!  The end number value that is 4 in the first and second line gets added up to become 8 so that creates the value `T1000,8,8` and that means I dont want that value anymore. The same with the bottom 3 where 8,4 and 8 add up to become 20, making the final value `S5214,20,20` which is then removed from the text file so the only lines left would be `S1234,2,4,Error` , `C1234,3,2,Error` and `S1348,4,2,Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should avoid doing operations and reading within the same context manager if you can help it. It makes the code harder to read. (flat is better than nested after all)

First, some setup: ignore this.

```
inp='''
T1000,8,4,Error
T1000,8,4,Error
S1234,2,4,Error
C1234,3,2,Error
S1348,4,2,Error
S5214,20,8,Error
S5214,20,4,Error
S5214,20,8,Error
'''.strip().splitlines(True)
```

This block of code above should give you the input string, similar to the following lines. For your case, use the following instead.

```
with open("target.txt","r") as f:
    inp = f.readlines()
```

Now, You need to collect all the lines that have similar keys at the start, and sum their values. We can use a defaultdict for this.

```
from collections import defaultdict    
temp = defaultdict(int) #this makes the default value 0.
```

Now, sum up the values. At this step, it helps to also store the 2nd value of each row in the key itself. against this value, we will make our equality check later.

```
for line in inp:
    k1, k2, v1, v2 = line.strip().split(',')
    temp[k1, int(k2)] += int(v1)
#Output:
defaultdict(int,
        {('T1000', 8): 8,
         ('S1234', 2): 4,
         ('C1234', 3): 2,
         ('S1348', 4): 2,
         ('S5214', 20): 20})
```

Now, get the key names for which the sums match up. these need to be removed.

```
to_remove = [k[0] for k, v in temp.items() if k[1] == v]
#Output:
['T1000', 'S5214']
```

Finally, write a condition based on what output you require. I assume you want all other lines to remain untouched.

```
output = [line for line in inp if not any(line.startswith(s) for s in to_remove)]
#Output:
['S1234,2,4,Error\n', 'C1234,3,2,Error\n', 'S1348,4,2,Error\n']
```

And then, just join and write back to a file.

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("".join(output))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Paritosh! Well I'm a self taught programmer by doing trial and error to get a lot of things working. I learnt using codeacademy. I would like to know how to use really efficient methods like the ones above and think like a programmer. Do you recommend any resources?

Comment: @AbidAbdulGafoor No worries, Self taught here as well. The biggest source of information for me has been stackoverflow itself really. One of the biggest things that will help you along is making sure you understand how you can use all the basic datatypes provided. Hashtables (or dicts in python) and sets provide some really powerful speedups to operations involving lookups. If you are looking for something as an overview for programming, i can recommend [this](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/) . However, the main thing to remember is to keep learning, SO is great for that.